# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine. Is the docker daemon running? - docker compose, windows 64

Tags: docker-compose

I have spring boot project and docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

When I run docker-compose up, I get this error:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine. Is the docker daemon running?

How can I fix it? (Windows 64)

Answer (score 0):

If under Windows, [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) must be running to provide the docker_engine.